# How to Display a div at same position on a any display irrespective of physical dimensions

Tags: html, css, screen, screen-resolution

I want to position the **add** div at the same place on any display whether physical dimensions of the displays are the same or not . How is it possible ?

```
<div id="iphone">
    <div id = "add" style="position:absolute; left:37%; top:23%; width:52%; height:77%; z-index:1">

           <iframe src='index.php/test.php' frameborder='1'; width='452%'; height='79%';scrolling='yes'; align='center';></iframe>
      </div>
</div>​
```

The css is :

```
#iphone 
{
width: 35%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 5%;
padding-left: 1px;
background: url("/debug-console/images/img_iphone.jpg") no-repeat;
background-position:center;  
}
#add 
{
margin: 0 0 0;
border: 0;
}
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
position: fixed;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
```

Will always make it be 50px from the top and left, regardless of anything, or use `position: absolute;` if you want it to scroll with the browser

Comment: there is no overriding code . i made the position attribute of add div as fixed but that is not what i desire .

Comment: If you notice, the OP is trying to target iPhone (judging from the ID).  `Position: fixed` is not supported on any version older than iOS 6.

Comment: Good spot, try `position: absolute;` OP

Comment: @cimmanon: iOS5 also supports position: fixed (although there bugs e.g. when the keyboard shows, page zooming. I don't know if position:fixed problems have been resolved in iOS6).

Answer (score 0):

When you use percentage to set the position, like `top:23%;`, then if you minimize the screen - the space is minimized too, therefore, you have to use pixels if you want the spaces to stay always the same. (for example- `top:100px;`)